# Adding and revoking permission to a specific user with a specific role

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I am using this package https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission for roles and permissions. In my application i have several roles like:

1. Users
2. Employers
3. Shop owners
4. Vendors

Depending on the level of trust i want each person in a specific role to have access to specific permissions only. For a user of role `user` with id `7` i want him or her to have permissions `editor`,'shopping` and no other permission.

Another user of id `65` in the same role `user` can have `editor`,'shopping`,'edit profile`,'view maps' permissions.

When i look at the docs https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/role-permissions/

can a user in a specific role be given a permission different from another user in the same role?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this.?

specific user role and permission you can manage

```php
$user = User::find(7);

$user->assignRole("user"); // assign role to that user

$user->givePermissionTo(['editor','shopping']); // for giving permission to user

$user->revokePermissionTo(['editor','shopping']); // for revoke permission to user
```

```php
$user = User::find(65);

$user->assignRole("user"); // assign role to that user

$user->givePermissionTo(['editor','shopping','edit profile']); // for giving permission to user

$user->revokePermissionTo(['editor','shopping','edit profile']); // for revoke permission to user
```

Comment: This will not do what the op wants, If you apply the permission to the role every user with that role will have have that permission.

Comment: @Remul i think he said user `7` will be having diffrent permission and user `65` will be having diffrent permission  and both role is same `user`

Comment: @KamleshPaul Yes thats what i said.  Same role but different permissions.

Comment: @Gandalf i hope it is working for you just you need to create role relationship as by default spatie comes with many to many user roles relationship

Comment: @KamleshPaul I shall try this out.

Comment: @Gandalf great ^_^

Comment: @KamleshPaul Yes but your code does not do that, you are applying the permissions to the role instead of the user, so every user with that role will have those permissions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Direct Permissions](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/direct-permissions/) for this.

From the docs:

> A permission can be given to any user:

```
$user->givePermissionTo('edit articles');

// You can also give multiple permission at once
$user->givePermissionTo('edit articles', 'delete articles');

// You may also pass an array
$user->givePermissionTo(['edit articles', 'delete articles']);
```

> A permission can be revoked from a user:

```
$user->revokePermissionTo('edit articles');

//Or revoke & add new permissions in one go:    
$user->syncPermissions(['edit articles', 'delete articles']);
```

In your case:

```
// assign the role to the user
$user->assignRole('user');

// assign the permissions to the user
$user->givePermissionTo(['editor', 'shopping', 'edit profile', 'view maps']);
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove a role, and not the Permissions, you can execute:

```
User::find(1)->removeRole('admin');
```

We are removing (revoking) the role 'admin' to the user with id 1.

This is done using the interactive shell with tinker.
To enter in Tinker execute:

```
php artisan tinker
```

Then you can find and modify entities:

[image]

In fact we can see here that the user has no more the role 'admin';

But still the role 'user', that is the basic.

[image]